# PSTricks LaTeX to Readable LaTeX Code Conversion

Tags: pstricks, conversion

I have opened the Editable PDF file in [Inkscape, Version: 0.48](http://inkscape.org/) and saved as `LaTeX with PSTricks macros`. Now i have the LaTeX file with `PSTRICKS` code. I am not familer with `pstricks` package and how to do pstricks latex code to normal LaTeX code. MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-tree,auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{STIXGeneral}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}
\begin{pspicture}(88.75,32.5)
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(24.625,17.065)
\lineto(26.703125,18.32525)
\lineto(29.96775,12.871125)
\lineto(33.625,29.125)
\lineto(85.5,29.125)
\lineto(85.5,28.382875)
\lineto(34.21875,28.382875)
\lineto(30.336,11.125)
\lineto(29.57525,11.125)
\lineto(25.9145,17.23925)
\lineto(24.8945,16.620625)
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(3.20947266,12.5)
\lineto(3.20947266,23.23730469)
\lineto(4.52783203,23.23730469)
\lineto(4.52783203,12.5)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(7.12109482,21.72119141)
\lineto(7.12109482,23.23730469)
\lineto(8.4394542,23.23730469)
\lineto(8.4394542,21.72119141)
\closepath
\moveto(7.12109482,12.5)
\lineto(7.12109482,20.27832031)
\lineto(8.4394542,20.27832031)
\lineto(8.4394542,12.5)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(11.36377072,12.5)
\lineto(11.36377072,20.27832031)
\lineto(12.54296994,20.27832031)
\lineto(12.54296994,19.18701172)
\curveto(12.78710815,19.56786403)(13.11181486,19.8742602)(13.51709104,20.10620117)
\curveto(13.92236093,20.33812693)(14.38378625,20.45409361)(14.90136838,20.45410156)
\curveto(15.47753515,20.45409361)(15.94994679,20.33446482)(16.31860471,20.09521484)
\curveto(16.68725074,19.85594968)(16.94726024,19.52147735)(17.098634,19.09179688)
\curveto(17.71386104,19.9999925)(18.51464149,20.45409361)(19.50097775,20.45410156)
\curveto(20.27245223,20.45409361)(20.86571336,20.24047078)(21.28076291,19.81323242)
\curveto(21.69579065,19.38597944)(21.90330998,18.72802112)(21.9033215,17.83935547)
\lineto(21.9033215,12.5)
\lineto(20.59228635,12.5)
\lineto(20.59228635,17.39990234)
\curveto(20.59227613,17.92724067)(20.54955156,18.30687896)(20.46411252,18.53881836)
\curveto(20.3786533,18.77074568)(20.22362416,18.95751307)(19.99902463,19.09912109)
\curveto(19.77440586,19.24071592)(19.51073424,19.31151663)(19.208009,19.31152344)
\curveto(18.66112572,19.31151663)(18.20702461,19.12963204)(17.84570432,18.76586914)
\curveto(17.48436908,18.40209371)(17.3037052,17.8198189)(17.30371213,17.01904297)
\lineto(17.30371213,12.5)
\lineto(15.98535275,12.5)
\lineto(15.98535275,17.55371094)
\curveto(15.98534714,18.1396428)(15.87792538,18.57909548)(15.66308713,18.87207031)
\curveto(15.44823831,19.1650324)(15.09667616,19.31151663)(14.60839963,19.31152344)
\curveto(14.23730202,19.31151663)(13.89428478,19.21386047)(13.5793469,19.01855469)
\curveto(13.2644026,18.82323586)(13.03613134,18.53759162)(12.89453244,18.16162109)
\curveto(12.7529285,17.78563925)(12.68212779,17.2436476)(12.6821301,16.53564453)
\lineto(12.6821301,12.5)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(2.81351471,3.875)
\lineto(4.45642853,6.21234131)
\lineto(2.93630981,8.37184143)
\lineto(3.88903046,8.37184143)
\lineto(4.57922363,7.31749725)
\curveto(4.70907397,7.11706982)(4.81352028,6.94910886)(4.89256287,6.81361389)
\curveto(5.01676714,6.99992058)(5.13109351,7.16505866)(5.2355423,7.30902863)
\lineto(5.9934845,8.37184143)
\lineto(6.903862,8.37184143)
\lineto(5.34986877,6.25468445)
\lineto(7.02242279,3.875)
\lineto(6.0866394,3.875)
\lineto(5.16355896,5.27232361)
\lineto(4.91796875,5.64917755)
\lineto(3.73659515,3.875)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(36.32958984,12.5)
\lineto(35.10644531,12.5)
\lineto(35.10644531,23.23730469)
\lineto(36.42480469,23.23730469)
\lineto(36.42480469,19.40673828)
\curveto(36.98144246,20.10497286)(37.69189096,20.45409361)(38.55615234,20.45410156)
\curveto(39.03466306,20.45409361)(39.48754347,20.35765816)(39.91479492,20.16479492)
\curveto(40.3420348,19.97191636)(40.69359695,19.70092053)(40.96948242,19.35180664)
\curveto(41.24535421,19.00267904)(41.46141844,18.58153689)(41.61767578,18.08837891)
\curveto(41.77391813,17.59520975)(41.85204305,17.06786653)(41.85205078,16.50634766)
\curveto(41.85204305,15.17333717)(41.52245354,14.14306476)(40.86328125,13.41552734)
\curveto(40.20409548,12.68798809)(39.41308065,12.32421893)(38.49023438,12.32421875)
\curveto(37.57226218,12.32421893)(36.85204805,12.70751932)(36.32958984,13.47412109)
\closepath
\moveto(36.31494141,16.44775391)
\curveto(36.31493922,15.5151337)(36.44189221,14.84130625)(36.69580078,14.42626953)
\curveto(37.11083686,13.74755735)(37.67235973,13.40820222)(38.38037109,13.40820312)
\curveto(38.95653814,13.40820222)(39.45458451,13.65844611)(39.87451172,14.15893555)
\curveto(40.29442742,14.65942167)(40.50438815,15.40527053)(40.50439453,16.39648438)
\curveto(40.50438815,17.41210446)(40.30297234,18.16161543)(39.90014648,18.64501953)
\curveto(39.49730908,19.12841134)(39.01024902,19.37011032)(38.43896484,19.37011719)
\curveto(37.86278923,19.37011032)(37.36474285,19.11986643)(36.94482422,18.61938477)
\curveto(36.52489994,18.11889087)(36.31493922,17.39501464)(36.31494141,16.44775391)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(76.5644536,13.45947266)
\curveto(76.07616678,13.04443305)(75.60619654,12.75146459)(75.15454149,12.58056641)
\curveto(74.70287713,12.40966806)(74.21825848,12.32421893)(73.70068407,12.32421875)
\curveto(72.84618954,12.32421893)(72.18945191,12.53295895)(71.73046923,12.95043945)
\curveto(71.27148408,13.36791905)(71.04199212,13.90136579)(71.04199266,14.55078125)
\curveto(71.04199212,14.93163819)(71.12866196,15.27953824)(71.30200243,15.59448242)
\curveto(71.4753413,15.90942042)(71.70239185,16.16210571)(71.98315477,16.35253906)
\curveto(72.26391473,16.54296471)(72.58007652,16.68700753)(72.9316411,16.78466797)
\curveto(73.19042747,16.85302299)(73.58105208,16.91894089)(74.1035161,16.98242188)
\curveto(75.16796456,17.10937039)(75.95165518,17.26073743)(76.45459032,17.43652344)
\curveto(76.45946717,17.61718238)(76.46190858,17.73192836)(76.46191454,17.78076172)
\curveto(76.46190858,18.31786528)(76.33739698,18.69628287)(76.08837938,18.91601562)
\curveto(75.75146007,19.21386047)(75.25097229,19.36278611)(74.58691454,19.36279297)
\curveto(73.96679389,19.36278611)(73.50903067,19.25414364)(73.21362352,19.03686523)
\curveto(72.91821095,18.81957376)(72.69970531,18.43505266)(72.55810595,17.88330078)
\lineto(71.26904345,18.05908203)
\curveto(71.38623006,18.61083373)(71.57910096,19.05638993)(71.84765673,19.39575195)
\curveto(72.1162098,19.73510019)(72.504393,19.99633039)(73.01220751,20.17944336)
\curveto(73.52001699,20.36254097)(74.10839531,20.45409361)(74.77734423,20.45410156)
\curveto(75.44140179,20.45409361)(75.98095203,20.37596869)(76.39599657,20.21972656)
\curveto(76.81102932,20.063469)(77.1162048,19.86693599)(77.31152391,19.63012695)
\curveto(77.50682941,19.39330365)(77.64354802,19.09423169)(77.72168016,18.73291016)
\curveto(77.76561821,18.50829477)(77.78759085,18.10302174)(77.78759813,17.51708984)
\lineto(77.78759813,15.75927734)
\curveto(77.78759085,14.53368937)(77.81566699,13.75854366)(77.87182665,13.43383789)
\curveto(77.92797156,13.10913025)(78.03905544,12.79785126)(78.2050786,12.5)
\lineto(76.82812548,12.5)
\curveto(76.69140054,12.77343723)(76.60351,13.09326113)(76.5644536,13.45947266)
\closepath
\moveto(76.45459032,16.40380859)
\curveto(75.97606922,16.20849239)(75.2582965,16.04247693)(74.30127001,15.90576172)
\curveto(73.75927456,15.82763339)(73.37597416,15.73974285)(73.15136766,15.64208984)
\curveto(72.92675586,15.54443055)(72.75341619,15.40160843)(72.63134813,15.21362305)
\curveto(72.50927581,15.02563224)(72.44824072,14.81689221)(72.44824266,14.58740234)
\curveto(72.44824072,14.23583811)(72.58129722,13.94286965)(72.84741259,13.70849609)
\curveto(73.11352325,13.47412012)(73.50292716,13.35693274)(74.01562548,13.35693359)
\curveto(74.52343395,13.35693274)(74.97509366,13.46801661)(75.37060595,13.69018555)
\curveto(75.76610849,13.9123521)(76.05663555,14.21630688)(76.24218798,14.60205078)
\curveto(76.38378366,14.89989994)(76.45458437,15.33935263)(76.45459032,15.92041016)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(84.06445122,15.34912109)
\lineto(85.36083794,15.18066406)
\curveto(85.21922915,14.28710759)(84.85668069,13.5876454)(84.27319145,13.08227539)
\curveto(83.68968967,12.57690422)(82.97313765,12.32421893)(82.12353325,12.32421875)
\curveto(81.05907706,12.32421893)(80.20336503,12.67211897)(79.55639458,13.36791992)
\curveto(78.90942101,14.06371914)(78.58593501,15.0610326)(78.58593559,16.35986328)
\curveto(78.58593501,17.19970233)(78.72509502,17.93456488)(79.00341606,18.56445312)
\curveto(79.28173509,19.19432924)(79.70531865,19.66674088)(80.27416801,19.98168945)
\curveto(80.84301283,20.29662306)(81.46190869,20.45409361)(82.13085747,20.45410156)
\curveto(82.97557905,20.45409361)(83.66649633,20.24047078)(84.20361137,19.81323242)
\curveto(84.74071401,19.38597944)(85.08495195,18.7792906)(85.23632622,17.99316406)
\lineto(83.95458794,17.79541016)
\curveto(83.83251179,18.31786528)(83.61644755,18.71093129)(83.30639458,18.97460938)
\curveto(82.99633099,19.23827451)(82.6215755,19.37011032)(82.182127,19.37011719)
\curveto(81.51806098,19.37011032)(80.97851074,19.13207345)(80.56347466,18.65600586)
\curveto(80.14843344,18.17992596)(79.94091412,17.42675289)(79.94091606,16.39648438)
\curveto(79.94091412,15.35155965)(80.14110923,14.59228306)(80.541502,14.11865234)
\curveto(80.94188968,13.64501839)(81.4643501,13.40820222)(82.10888481,13.40820312)
\curveto(82.62645831,13.40820222)(83.05858678,13.56689346)(83.40527153,13.88427734)
\curveto(83.75194547,14.20165845)(83.97167181,14.68993922)(84.06445122,15.34912109)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(13.70935822,7.58425903)
\curveto(14.08479376,7.17493872)(14.40942417,6.86371695)(14.68325043,6.6505928)
\curveto(14.95706156,6.43746311)(15.21535446,6.27867649)(15.45812988,6.17423248)
\lineto(15.45812988,5.98368835)
\curveto(15.17865711,5.84818833)(14.90766128,5.67528735)(14.6451416,5.46498489)
\curveto(14.38260688,5.25467925)(14.06926796,4.94628036)(13.7051239,4.53978729)
\lineto(13.37908173,4.53978729)
\curveto(13.64442555,5.10718413)(13.92247855,5.54331803)(14.21324158,5.84819031)
\lineto(7.4595108,5.84819031)
\lineto(7.4595108,6.27585602)
\lineto(14.21324158,6.27585602)
\curveto(13.99869613,6.54967231)(13.84908385,6.75291918)(13.7644043,6.88559723)
\curveto(13.67971146,7.01826926)(13.55409361,7.25115629)(13.38755035,7.58425903)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(18.79244292,7.31326294)
\curveto(19.08884168,7.68587876)(19.32031728,7.93146872)(19.48687041,8.05003357)
\curveto(19.71269665,8.21375604)(19.95122943,8.29561936)(20.20246947,8.29562378)
\curveto(20.49886682,8.29561936)(20.77621411,8.18835018)(21.03451216,7.97381592)
\curveto(21.2927999,7.75927346)(21.42194634,7.4134715)(21.42195189,6.936409)
\curveto(21.42194634,6.6033069)(21.3739575,6.34148542)(21.27798522,6.15094376)
\curveto(21.18200212,5.96039754)(21.03238985,5.80725667)(20.82914793,5.69152069)
\curveto(20.62589611,5.57578108)(20.4170035,5.51791218)(20.20246947,5.51791382)
\curveto(19.95122943,5.51791218)(19.71269665,5.59836406)(19.48687041,5.75926971)
\curveto(19.32031728,5.88065138)(19.08884168,6.12765278)(18.79244292,6.50027466)
\curveto(18.40852925,6.01756072)(18.00062408,5.77620507)(17.56872618,5.77620697)
\curveto(17.2836143,5.77620507)(17.03873005,5.88417997)(16.83407271,6.10013199)
\curveto(16.62941345,6.31607956)(16.52708429,6.58495823)(16.52708495,6.9067688)
\curveto(16.52708429,7.22575043)(16.62941345,7.49392338)(16.83407271,7.71128845)
\curveto(17.03873005,7.92864585)(17.2836143,8.03732647)(17.56872618,8.03733063)
\curveto(18.00062408,8.03732647)(18.40852925,7.79597081)(18.79244292,7.31326294)
\closepath
\moveto(19.08461058,6.91100311)
\curveto(19.33019734,6.5299122)(19.55461575,6.26879643)(19.7578665,6.12765503)
\curveto(19.88771478,6.03449796)(20.03309275,5.98792056)(20.19400084,5.98792267)
\curveto(20.40853488,5.98792056)(20.58849304,6.066961)(20.73387587,6.22504425)
\curveto(20.87924898,6.3831228)(20.95193796,6.60612978)(20.95194304,6.89406586)
\curveto(20.95193796,7.19328739)(20.87783754,7.42194012)(20.72964156,7.58002472)
\curveto(20.58143586,7.73810191)(20.39724339,7.81714236)(20.17706358,7.8171463)
\curveto(20.0387385,7.81714236)(19.90888633,7.77762213)(19.7875067,7.69858551)
\curveto(19.62377614,7.58848963)(19.38947767,7.32596243)(19.08461058,6.91100311)
\closepath
\moveto(18.50027525,6.9067688)
\curveto(18.27444278,7.18905308)(18.09377889,7.37042268)(17.95828307,7.45087814)
\curveto(17.82278307,7.53132645)(17.69293091,7.57155239)(17.56872618,7.57155609)
\curveto(17.40499785,7.57155239)(17.26879422,7.5136835)(17.16011488,7.39794922)
\curveto(17.05143298,7.2822079)(16.99709267,7.12271556)(16.9970938,6.91947174)
\curveto(16.99709267,6.7190447)(17.05355014,6.55884665)(17.16646636,6.43887711)
\curveto(17.27937999,6.31890243)(17.41628934,6.25891638)(17.57719481,6.25891876)
\curveto(17.8623033,6.25891638)(18.16999647,6.47486617)(18.50027525,6.9067688)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(59.42480469,17.18017578)
\lineto(52.33496094,17.18017578)
\lineto(52.33496094,18.41064453)
\lineto(59.42480469,18.41064453)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(46.6155777,19.98253632)
\lineto(46.6155777,19.25)
\lineto(42.51252747,19.25)
\curveto(42.50688146,19.43348675)(42.53652163,19.60991633)(42.60144806,19.77928925)
\curveto(42.70589401,20.05875316)(42.87314925,20.33398329)(43.10321426,20.60498047)
\curveto(43.33327757,20.87597494)(43.66567089,21.18931386)(44.1003952,21.54499817)
\curveto(44.77506004,22.09827901)(45.23095405,22.53653007)(45.46807861,22.85975266)
\curveto(45.70519674,23.18296802)(45.82375741,23.48854404)(45.82376099,23.77648163)
\curveto(45.82375741,24.07852453)(45.71578251,24.33328883)(45.49983597,24.5407753)
\curveto(45.28388292,24.74825119)(45.00230132,24.85199177)(44.65509033,24.85199738)
\curveto(44.28811442,24.85199177)(43.99453561,24.74189972)(43.77435303,24.52172089)
\curveto(43.5541674,24.30153151)(43.44266391,23.99666121)(43.43984222,23.60710907)
\lineto(42.65649414,23.68756104)
\curveto(42.71012832,24.27189134)(42.91196375,24.71719958)(43.26200104,25.02348709)
\curveto(43.6120363,25.32976305)(44.08204468,25.48290392)(44.67202759,25.48291016)
\curveto(45.2676514,25.48290392)(45.73907122,25.31776584)(46.08628845,24.98749542)
\curveto(46.43349801,24.65721353)(46.60710471,24.24789692)(46.60710907,23.75954437)
\curveto(46.60710471,23.51112703)(46.556293,23.2669485)(46.45467377,23.02700806)
\curveto(46.35304613,22.78706006)(46.18437946,22.53441291)(45.94867325,22.26906586)
\curveto(45.71295964,22.00371276)(45.32128599,21.63956212)(44.77365112,21.17661285)
\curveto(44.31634315,20.79270018)(44.02276434,20.53229013)(43.89291382,20.39538193)
\curveto(43.76306001,20.25847143)(43.65579083,20.12085637)(43.57110596,19.98253632)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(67.59863281,12.5)
\lineto(67.59863281,15.07080078)
\lineto(62.94042969,15.07080078)
\lineto(62.94042969,16.27929688)
\lineto(67.84033203,23.23730469)
\lineto(68.91699219,23.23730469)
\lineto(68.91699219,16.27929688)
\lineto(70.3671875,16.27929688)
\lineto(70.3671875,15.07080078)
\lineto(68.91699219,15.07080078)
\lineto(68.91699219,12.5)
\closepath
\moveto(67.59863281,16.27929688)
\lineto(67.59863281,21.12060547)
\lineto(64.23681641,16.27929688)
\closepath
}
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Looks like a laborious way to write `\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt{b^2-4ac}` into an otherwise blank document using graphical commands.

Answer (score 3):

The PDF produced from the code in the question looks similar to what would be produced from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt{b^2-4ac}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

So it looks like a laborious way of writing a formula with graphical commands.

Comment: I have more pstricks LaTeX code and need for PSTricks LaTeX code to Normal LaTeX Code Conversion (like your answer). It is possible?

Comment: Inkscape is a drawing program, not a typesetting program! You should use it for the purpose it was made for: Creating line (vector) graphics that **may** later be embedded into text documents. If you want to write text documents (articles, presentations, books) with LaTeX, use a text editor (Vi, Emacs, TeXWorks, Notepad, ...) to write the LaTeX code, and run some variety of LaTeX (`pdflatex`, `xelatex`, ...) on it to produce a PDF.